# Uses protobuf-c 0.15 on an embedded ARM system (STM32 F4)

Tags: c, arm, protocol-buffers, stm32

Is it possible to develop a system which uses protobuf-c 0.15 on an embedded ARM system (STM32 F4) and communicates with a java server, which uses protobuf?

protobuf-c 0.15 uses dynamic memory allocation. And compiling throw error:

```
/opt/arm/sourcery-arm-none-eabi-2011.09/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.6.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb2/libc.a(lib_a-abort.o): In function `abort':
abort.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `_exit'
/opt/arm/sourcery-arm-none-eabi-2011.09/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.6.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb2/libc.a(lib_a-sbrkr.o): In function `_sbrk_r':
sbrkr.c:(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `_sbrk'
...
```

I know about nanopb and protobuf-embedded-c. But they have limited support protobuf.

Comment: Seems you need to link against libc. Or if libc doesn't support malloc, then you can't use this.

Comment: What java protobuf library do you use by any chance? As far as i know the RPC layer of Google doesnt specify the "wire" protocol, so any c to java comms requires a compatible java and c library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The undefined reference to `_sbrk` is from newlib, the libc that comes with CodeSourcery. You will need to provide system call functions to properly interface it to your system. See for example:
https://sites.google.com/site/stm32discovery/open-source-development-with-the-stm32-discovery/getting-newlib-to-work-with-stm32-and-code-sourcery-lite-eabi

(With regards to nanopb's limited support of protobuf, I would like to hear more about what features you would need. I'm the author of nanopb.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Our main problem with using nanopb:
We already have a well-honed protocol that uses reflection. Stm32 device - this is another client, who must support it. The whole difficulty is that all the information about the message we have is in the message itself.

Comment: @K.G.V. Ok. I have considered whether reflection support could be useful in nanopb also. If you want, feel free to file a feature request and include an example of the kind of .proto you would like to use.